# Entity Framework Code First, MVC, SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with code-first approach

My model:

```
public class Articles
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Wymagane podanie tytułu!")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wymagane podanie krótkiego opisu!")]
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wymagane podanie treści!")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

My connection strings in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ArticlesSConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=BazaA;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Context:

```
public class ArticlesContext : DbContext
{
    public ArticlesContext() : base("ArticlesConnectionString") { }
    public DbSet<Articles> ArticlesS { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addArticle(Articles article)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View("Index", article); }
        else
        {
            ArticlesContext db = new ArticlesContext();

                db.ArticlesS.Add(article);
                db.SaveChanges();

            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

on line:

```
db.ArticlesS.Add(article);
```

I have no idea what is wrong...

Comment: What is the entire exception detail?

Comment: Error 26:


Additional information: An error has occurred with the network or appearance when establishing a connection to the server SQL Server. Can not find server or is not available. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the server configuration SQL Server allows remote connections. (Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating a particular server / instance)

Comment: ArticlesSConnectionString != ArticlesConnectionString

Comment: eh....
now, error disappeared but base wasnt created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to services and start SQL Server or your Conn string is not good I think that you must have Context class name inside Connection string,

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ArticlesContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\BazaA.mdf; Initial Catalog=BazaA;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I have mistake with code(typo), now its working but base arent creating...

Comment: I think the name should be as Context class and in DataSource you must also have database name but if it works then ok

Comment: Context class: ArticlesStrContext 
connstr: ArticlesStrConnectionString
and stil didt create

Comment: If your base isn't created I think your connection string should be more like this just add another conn string copy above one below that one in web.config and change name and to your ContextClass name and so on

Comment: Name it as your context class ArticlesContext just use one you already have in web.config and copy below that and change this information which I post in answer It must work under existing Connection string in web.config just new one copy from that one and insert your name as Context class name and insert dataSource and InitialCatlog

Comment: Ok then I didn't help you base is created now ?

Comment: Its weird and I dont know what was wrong but I thank you for your time :)

Comment: No problem I though it was connection string but it works that is the most important